# How did "everloving" become a completely generic intensifier?

Tags: etymology, adjectives, slang

Most of the uses of the word *everloving* I can think of involve either vulgar or violent contexts, so you must excuse the following example:

> He'd finally crossed my last nerve, so yesterday, me and my buddies caught him out and beat the **everloving** snot out of him.

When I look up the definition of *everloving* at [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/everloving), it gives me the following three definitions:

> 1. Which loves unceasingly or unconditionally
> 2. Of or related to one who is everloving (1), or to everlasting love
> 3. Which is loved unceasingly

And the fourth states, "generic intensifier."

So I have to two questions:  First, is the premise of my question wrong?  Is there a phrase where *everloving* is used as an intensifier, and still manages to add a meaning more than making the phrase stronger?  Secondly, how did *everloving* assume this role? How is the fourth definition of *everloving* connected to its first three definitions?  Can anyone find or draw a plausible path?

Comment: I don't think it's that unusual for slang generic intensifiers to *only* have 'negative' connotations. That particularly applies to euphemisms, though I think it's rare to find *bleeding*, for example, amplifying a positive meaning. So you could say that while *everloving* partly just intensifies whatever follows, it may also clarify that what follows should be interpreted negatively rather than positively.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe it's a euphemism for "motherf***ing", with a similar sound and a meaning close enough to be understood but not actually obscene.

Comment: It's more comment than answer.

Comment: This is a by all means answer. You couldn't get a better answer unless you could either find evidence for this path or give another plausible path.

Comment: @Peter Shor I didn't downvote it.

Comment: @Peter Shor: Is there any explanation in this answer about "First, is the premise of my question wrong? Is there a phrase where everloving is used as an intensifier, and still manages to add a meaning more than making the phrase stronger? Secondly, how did everloving assume this role? How is the fourth definition of everloving connected to its first three definitions? Can anyone find or draw a plausible path?"? .. I haven't heard "everloving" before, so I'm curious to know the answer and I didn't find it here.

Comment: @Boob: First, the path to intensifier is *euphemism for motherf***ing.* If this is indeed the path, I doubt you are going to get any more detail than that. So for the second part of the question, this is a perfectly good answer. Answers on StackOverflow don't have to answer **all** the parts of the question to qualify as good answers. It's not like a history test.

Comment: @Peter Shor: So, I have to know more about differences between comment and answer on EL&U. I thought the complete answer should answer all parts of the question, my mistake.

Comment: @Boob: clearly, it's a judgment call as to how partial an answer can be and still be acceptable, but the FAQ say that an answer that is "not even a *partial* answer to the actual question" can be removed.

Comment: @Boob: I don't *know* it's a euphemism with the suggested derivation, but I've no reason to doubt it, and no plausible alternative. On the other hand it's not unheard-of to **beat the sweet shit** out of someone. Violent people are prone to visit their violence upon everything, including language.

Comment: @PeterShor : so are you saying that if I know part of the answer but not all I shouldn't say anything?

Comment: @TimLymington: No, I'm saying that if you know part of the answer, you are allowed to post it as an answer (you could also post it as a comment, especially if it's only a small part of the answer). There's a double negative in my comment above which makes it easily misunderstood.

Comment: For those curious how it took that path, I've always assumed it went through http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/motherloving to get there.

Comment: I believe that "everloving" was deliberately used as a euphemistic variation on an unacceptable word in the script of West Side Story, but I've not been able to find a cite for that. My impression was that in this sense that is the origin of the word, but I'm not sure about that bit.

Comment: According to Green's _Dictionary of Slang_ the term _everloving_ in this sense appeared in 1919, at the same time as the first printed appearance of _motherfucking_. It predates Runyon's coinage of the word to mean _wife_.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Tim Lymington's appraisal, it was the first thing that came to mind -"motherf**king", which was softened to "motherloving". That's still offensive by its connotations if not the hard language in it. Therefore "everloving" is a further softening of the phrase.

This is, of course, conjecture, but I'm happily convinced by it :)

Answer (score 0):

the phrase is also associated with God and Jesus...now I'm wondering if there is a similar quirk in other religious societies - that of invoking the name of God
or Jesus (Allah, Buddah, etc.) to denote intensity. A shorthand for emphasis, rather than repeat a thought many times...

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage! We're looking for long answers that provide some [explanation and context](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with [citations](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). Answers that don't include explanations may be [removed](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers).